# Помогите справиться с глюком в VBA

Tags: vba

Есть простая программа, написанная на VBA:

```
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
    grana.Value = True
End Sub

Private Sub Schet_Click()
    Set vyvod = Range(Rez)
    Set d = Range(diap).CurrentRegion
    percent = percent.Value
    gran = gran.Value
    diap = diap.Value
    Rez = Rez.Value
    m = d.Rows.Count
    n = d.Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To m
        For j = 1 To n
            percentcount = d.Cells(i, j).Value * percent / 100

            If grana = True And percentcount < gran Then
                percentcount = gran
                vyvod.Cells(i, j).Value = percentcount
                vyvod.Cells(i, j + 5).Value = gran
            Else
                percentcount = percentcount
                vyvod.Cells(i, j).Value = percentcount
            End If    
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Vyhod_click()
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Вопрос заключается вот в чем.
Если установлена отметка "Использовать границу (grana) и значение параметра percentcount < gran (gran вводится с клавиатуры), то надо percentcount присваивать значение gran.
Однако в результате срабатывания программы gran присваивается всем величинам при выборе grana. Вопрос, где может быть проблема?

Comment: Вам личные убеждения не позволяют отформатировать код с отступами?

Answer (score 2):

В общем, оказалось, что решить эту проблему достаточно просто. Необходимо было всего лишь преобразовать gran в число. Сделать это удалось при помощи Val. Val(gran) - вот так.